# show that $\int e^{-y} (s-y)^{n-2} dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to show that

$$\int e^{-y} (s-y)^{n-2} dy= -e^{-s} (s-y)^n (y-s)^{-n} \Gamma(n-1, y-s)+C;$$

I tried in Wolfram Alpha but but does not show the step by step.

for n>2

Comment: try with $n=2$: does your equality make sense?

Comment: for n>2, I also need to value from y = 0 to y = s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\begin{align}
F(\infty)-F(x)&=\int_x^\infty e^{-y} (s-y)^{n-2} \operatorname{d}y\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{-s}(-1)^n\int_{x-s}^\infty e^{-t} t^{n-2} \operatorname{d}t \qquad(t=s-y)\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{-s}(-1)^n\Gamma(n-1,x-s)
\end{align}
$$
so
$$
F(x)=\operatorname{e}^{-s}(-1)^{n+1}\Gamma(n-1,x-s)+C
$$

Comment: good answer alexjo